# Comparing 3 variable in SQL case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am comparing 3 variables values from the table for that I am using the case statement.

Here is the image of the table.

[image]

What I am trying is this SQL select query.

```
select a,b,c,
case(
    when (a=b=c) then "Equilateral"
    when a!=b!=c then "Scalene"
    when a=b!=c or a!=b=c then "Isosceles"
    else "Not A Triangle"
    end as Text
)
from TRIANGLES;
```

Error I am getting is shown in the image below.

[image]

Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use parentheses to wrap the `WHEN` clauses.

Comment: I have first tried without parenthesis that was also not working.

Comment: You're getting an Oracle error message from MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh I was posting my answers on Hackersrank so it was just the tab of oracle otherwise I was using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rewrite your expressions, this is not supported.

```
select a,b,c,
case
    when (a=b) and (b=c) then 'Equilateral'
    when (a!=b) and (b!=c) then 'Scalene'
    when (a=b and b!=c) or (a!=b and b=c) then 'Isosceles'
    else 'Not A Triangle'
    end as [Text]

from triangles;
```

Comment: Getting this error again.
when (a=b) and (b=c) then "Equilateral" 
* 
ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussain, 2 issues, use single quotes on string values, then `Text` is a reserved keyword so you need to wrap

Comment: Worked Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot chain comparisons like `a = b = c`, you need to explicitly write them separately and combine their results:

```
when (a = b AND a = c) then "Equilateral"
when (a != b AND b != c AND c != a) then "Scalene"
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare 3 operands at a time. You need to split it using and operator.

```
select a,b,c,
case(
   when (a=b and b=c) then 'Equilateral'
   when (a!=b and b!=c and c!=a) then 'Scalene'
   when (a=b and b!=c) or (a!=b and b=c) then 'Isosceles'
   else 'Not A Triangle' 
     end as Text
   )
from TRIANGLES;
```